# facebook app crashes because of SSL certificate

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, ssl

[image]I am using Facebook app request. When the user is redirected to the following page, this page craches (he gets the Facebook canvas wrapping some 404-like icon). I think I don't have SSL certificate although `Facebook Connect` is possible. How can I be sure that this is the error comes from `SSL` ?

https://apps.facebook.com/somesite/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=some_request&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_request

Update :

Here's what my console outputs

```
for (;;); {"t":"fullReload","seq":0}
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":[],"bootloadable":{},"ixData":{}}
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":{"payload_source":"unknown"},"bootloadable":{},"ixData":{}}
for (;;); {"t":"heartbeat"}
{"t":"heartbeat"}
{"t":"continue"}
{
"version": 9, 
"client_version": "0.9.12.10.g89b2a4fc", 
"playing": true, 
"shuffle": false, 
"repeat": false, 
"play_enabled": true, 
"prev_enabled": true, 
"next_enabled": true, 
"track": {
  "track_resource": {
    "name": "Country Practice", 
    "uri": "spotify:track:1pczW91sol6LcXtIf2mR5G", 
    "location": {
      "og": "http://open.spotify.com/track/1pczW91sol6LcXtIf2mR5G"
    }
  }, 
  "artist_resource": {
    "name": "Wibutee", 
    "uri": "spotify:artist:53p1c0Fnb6srjMorsglFu7", 
    "location": {
      "og": "http://open.spotify.com/artist/53p1c0Fnb6srjMorsglFu7"
    }
  }, 
  "album_resource": {
    "name": "Playmachine", 
    "uri": "spotify:album:0oXJO0mcHw3fa9yS2tSbq4", 
    "location": {
      "og": "http://open.spotify.com/album/0oXJO0mcHw3fa9yS2tSbq4"
    }
  }, 
  "length": 236, 
  "track_type": "normal"
}, 
"context": {
  "context_resource": {
    "name": "", 
    "uri": "spotify:artist:53p1c0Fnb6srjMorsglFu7", 
    "location": {
      "og": "http://open.spotify.com/artist/53p1c0Fnb6srjMorsglFu7"
    }
  }
}, 
"playing_position": 59.04, 
"server_time": 1409300318, 
"volume": 0.63749141, 
"active_user": {
  "uri": "spotify:user:benchoufi", 
  "canonical_username": "benchoufi", 
  "real_name": "Benchoufi Mehdi", 
  "location": {
    "og": "http://open.spotify.com/user/benchoufi"
  }
}, 
"online": true, 
"open_graph_state": {
  "private_session": false, 
  "posting_disabled": false
}, 
"running": true
}
```

and several files which outputs this

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":{"time":1409300345000,"buddy_list":{"nowAvailableList":{"502238078":{"i":false,"a":2,"p":{"status":"active","webStatus":"active","fbAppStatus":"idle","messengerStatus":"offline","otherStatus":"offline"}},"505212218":{"i":false,"a":2,"p":...
```

Update 2

[image]

Comment: You could start with actually posting an error message if any, or a screenshot with your question. Otherwise it will be tough to give you some help.

Comment: @Tobi I put some image and I don't get any message error...

Comment: What does the browser output in the developer tools under network connections?

Comment: @Tobi I put outputs of files in the network tools

Comment: I didn't mean the console output. If you're using chrome, what do you see under the network tab of the developer tools when you try to access your app in FB?

Comment: @Tobi I updated my post, I added some picture > is that what you're talking about. If it is, my first update list the content of the responses of each file

Comment: _“How can I be sure that this is the error comes from SSL ?”_ – the browser console should be able to tell you that already.